# Inno Setup Log setup exit code

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

The Inno Setup log file does not, by default, include the setup exit code. I am looking for a way to include this in the log file. I am assuming this would be done using the `Log` function and including it in the `DeinitializeSetup` event. Something like this:

```pascal
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  Log('Exit code: ' + ExitCode);
end;
```

What I don't know, and cannot seem to find, is how to return the setup exit code, so that I can use it in the `Log` function. Is this the best way to do this and how do I return the setup exit code?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I want to be able to see if a certain condition has occurred, whereby I set a custom exit code (9), which means that the `IntializeSetup` has exited due to Windows Updates requiring a reboot.

Comment: So you are using the `GetCustomSetupExitCode` already?

Comment: No, as far as I am aware `GetCustomSetupExitCode` can only be used if Setup completed and would have returned a 0 exit code. I set the exit code in the `InitializeSetup` event using `procedure ExitProcess(ExitCode: Integer);
  external 'ExitProcess@kernel32.dll stdcall';`

Comment: If you call `ExitProcess`, the process is aborted immediately. No Pascal Code is called after, not even the `DeinitializeSetup`.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. Maybe I need to ask a new question on whether there is way to set the exit code in `InitializeSetup` less forcefully. Would there be a way to return an exit code if this was the case?

Comment: No, there's no better way, afaik.

Comment: You can of course log something before you call the `ExitProcess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to retrieve the exit code in Pascal Script.

All you can do is to log, if installation was successful or not (what is logged anyway already).

One way to do that is by checking, if [the `GetCustomSetupExitCode` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=GetCustomSetupExitCode) was called or not (it's called when exit code would be 0 only).

```pascal
var
  ZeroExitCode: Boolean;

function GetCustomSetupExitCode: Integer;
begin
  ZeroExitCode := True;
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  if ZeroExitCode then
    Log('Zero exit code')
  else
    Log('Non-zero exit code');
end;
```